# How can i query to retrieve all the records as well as records that are shared to a user?

Tags: record

I have a requirement to query all records that a user owns for a specific object  as well as shared to that user.
ex: Need to send the nightly job for all opportunities that are marked as high value as well as opportunities that are shared to me which are high value. How to write the query for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Share object for `Opportunity` : which is called : `OpportunityShare`:

```
select OpportunityId, OpportunityAccessLevel, RowCause, UserOrGroupId from OpportunityShare where UserOrGroupId = '<your_user_id>' and RowCause='Owner'
```

And if you want to get the records that are shared with the user you can use this query :

```
select OpportunityId, OpportunityAccessLevel, RowCause, UserOrGroupId from OpportunityShare where UserOrGroupId = '<your_user_id>' and (RowCause = 'Rule' or RowCause = 'Manual' )
```

The `RowCause` field means the reason for the record sharing, it might be `Owner`(if the user is the owner of the record), `Rule`(if the record is shared by a sharing rule), `Manual`(if it's Manual Sharing),...etc

These are some useful link for the Share object :

[link 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)

[link 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm)

I hope this help you